# Tell me the user is inactive it shows the alert in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$credentials = Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1], $request->remember);


     if ($credentials && Auth::user()->role_id == 2) {
       
            return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
         }
         elseif ($credentials && Auth::user()->role_id == 3) {
       
            return redirect('/agent/dashboard');
        }
         elseif ($credentials && Auth::user()->role_id == 4) {
             return redirect('/');
        }else{

             return redirect('login')->with('error', 'Opps! You have entered invalid credentials');

         }      
           
          
}
```

Please tell me any above code login access. when the user is inactive it shows the message

Comment: what are you asking here actually?? your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show use is active or not by storing that in session and read from session.

To store in session

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

For More [Laravel Global Session](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#the-global-session-helper)

To retrieve data from session
[Laravel get Session value](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#retrieving-all-session-data)

Once you show error from session, delete that session value.

[Laravel Delete Session Value](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#deleting-data)